# SecItemAdd on OS X not working, on iOS is

Tags: ios, macos, key, private, keychain

I have a problem. 
I have working Code for iOS to add a private Key to the Keychain by SecItemAdd. It works without any error.
On OS X with the same attributes and values, it does not work.
Any ideas, whats the problem. Here is the part of the Code:

```
NSData * keyData = ...
NSString * name = @"TestKey"
NSString * keyID = @"TestKey"
const id keys[]     = {
        (__bridge id)(kSecClass),
        (__bridge id)(kSecAttrKeyClass),
        (__bridge id)(kSecAttrLabel),
        (__bridge id)(kSecAttrApplicationLabel),
        (__bridge id)(kSecAttrIsPermanent),
        (__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccessible),
        (__bridge id)(kSecValueData) };
const id values[]   = {
        (__bridge id)(kSecClassKey),
        (__bridge id)(kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate),
        name,
        keyID,
        (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
        (__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock),
        keyData };
NSMutableDictionary * attributes    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys count:ATTR_COUNT(keys)];

CFTypeRef       result;
NSError * error = nil;

OSStatus osStatus = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes, &result);
```

The error is:

> 25303  (errKCNoSuchAttr / errSecNoSuchAttr:  / The attribute does not
>   exist.).)

Comment: For what it's worth, I am finding that SecItemCopyMatching() code that works on iOS to retrieve public key bits does not work on OSX.  It always returns 96 bytes, regardless of key size.

Answer (score 3):

The Error code specifies `The attribute does not exist`, it is due to the attribute : `kSecAttrKeyClass`. Try removing this attribute, and use tag names to distinguish the different keys. I was also getting similar issue in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Which OS X version are you trying to support? OS X Keychain Services are different than iOS Keychain Services. For example, kSecClass is only available as of OS X 10.7, and kSecAttrAccessible 10.9.